# Using node_view() to display a node doesn't print local menu items

Tags: 7, hooks, routes

When using node_view() to display a node (via return from a function that's called in hook_menu()) the usual View/Edit tabs are missing.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is expected. The reason they are there, is because the path of view a node is at `node/[nid]` and the edit/view is at `node/[nid]/edit`. If you changed the default node path with hook_menu_alter the tabs on all nodes would disappear.

The reason they are there, is because they are of type, `MENU_LOCAL_TASK`, check out the documentation on [`hook_menu`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), if you need to know more.

Answer (score 3):

It is the expected behavior. [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/6)'s purpose is to build the node view, not to create also the other tabs that you normally see at `http://example.com/node/<nid>`.

If you want to emulate what done in a node page, you should define the following menu structure (I have chosen `page` randomly):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['page/%node'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'node_page_title', 
    'title arguments' => array(1), 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page_view', 
    'page arguments' => array(1), 
    'access callback' => 'node_access', 
    'access arguments' => array('view', 1), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  $items['page/%node/view'] = array(
    'title' => 'View', 
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, 
    'weight' => -10,
  );
  $items['page/%node/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit', 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page_edit', 
    'page arguments' => array(1), 
    'access callback' => 'node_access', 
    'access arguments' => array('update', 1), 
    'weight' => 1, 
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

`mymodule_page_view()` is the page callback that would call `node_view()`.

Answer (score 1):

To move all potential tabs added by modules to a node, and make them visible on another new custom path alter the links dynamically when the menu cache router is re-built.

Stick the following in a module:

```
    /**
 * Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
 */
function example_menu_alter(&$callbacks) { 
  foreach($callbacks as $path => $menu) {
    $callbacks[$path];

    if (strpos($path, 'node/%node/') !== FALSE) {
      $newpath = str_replace('node/%node/', 'customurl/%/%/%/%node/', $path);
      $callbacks[$newpath] = $menu;
      unset ($callbacks[$path]);
    }
  }
}
```